# Nodemcu 8266 has not display text on LCD

Tags: display, esp8266, nodemcu, lcd

I am using nodemcu esp8266 with LCD for the first time and I'm unable to make it work. It lights the background but it does not show any text.

LCD Address: 0x27
sda: d4
sdl: d3
vnn: vin
gnd: gnd

Code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

//Set LCD Address 0x27 for LCD1602 (16 chars 2 line display)
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  lcd.begin(0,2);  // SDA-0 (GPIO D3 = 0), SCL-2 (GPIO D4 = 2)  

  lcd.backlight();

  lcd.print("Hello world");

}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: use pins D1 as SCL and D2 as SCA at least while you test it. https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/75704/what-are-the-best-gpio-pins-to-use-for-my-project/75706#75706

Comment: I changed D1  as SCL and  D2 as SCA but  LCD not display as it was.

Comment: I changed the library from the original to https://github.com/fdebrabander/Arduino-LiquidCrystal-I2C-library LCD can display text.

Answer (score -1):

I changed the library from the original to https://github.com/fdebrabander/Arduino-LiquidCrystal-I2C-library LCD can display text.